# Internal Error: no cycle found for node

Tags: scons

When running scons in single thread, I get all my code to build fine.  However, if I use `-j` (for parallel builds), I get a plethora of these errors:

```
 Internal Error: no cycle found for node FILE (<SCons.Node.FS.Dir object at 0xc15aeec>) in state pending
```

What does this error mean?

How can I resolve this?

I am aware of [Issue 2777](http://scons.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2777) but I am running scons v2.3.1 which should have this already in.

Comment: I dont know what that exact error means, but I know that when building in parallel with SCons, if your build scripts changes the directory, then you can run into problems. Do you have anything in your scripts that changes directories? something like os.system('cd'), etc

Comment: Yes, I do but they are wrapped with env['SPAWN'] calls.  Or they all should be ^_~

Comment: Try running scons with --debug=stacktrace flag to get more info..

Comment: @bdbaddog: This produced several gig of log log files and is not helpful. The project was badly set up and I am trying to clean it up...

Comment: Can you pastebin a few hundred lines.. it may point at something. You got gig's of stacktrace lines?

Comment: @bdbaddog: Yup. Code base is around a million lines of code, split into modules, libraries, and about 100 git repos.

Comment: A million lines of python code in your SCons based build system? Or built by SCons?

Comment: @bdbaddog: ^_~, It is lines of C++/Python code, not scons scripts. The former is 15639 lines of code/comment over 327 SConscripts.

Comment: Can you send a snippet of the stack trace from SCons? I don't need any of the compile log.. Or ideally create a small testcase you can share which reproduces the issue.

Comment: @bdbaddog: Sure, it's going to take a while as I am in middle of doing something else... Thanks for the help! It is much appreciated!!!

Comment: @bdbaddog: `scons --debug=stacktrace -j 3 > log 2>&1` should print all the debug output should it not?...

Comment: FYI, Issue 2777 is still open. Seems to be caused by SideEffect builder.

Comment: I just upgraded from 2.4.1 to 2.5.1 and now get this error. What is the solution?

Comment: @rkemp There is no solution. You have a cyclic dependency somewhere. Good luck finding where.

Comment: Try running scons version 2.3.0

Comment: @cako How does downgrading to 2.3.0 help?

Comment: From what I could gather online, at some point they introduced checking for dependency cycles that were previously not caught. I suppose ideally the code should be updated by the developers, but that was impossible for the program I was running. So I tried downgrading and it works now!

Comment: @cako Ignoring the problem is not a viable solution.

Comment: Ok then, worked for me. Good luck

Comment: @cako No, it did not work for you. You just do not see the error any more…

Comment: This has to be a SCons bug. I've moved a source directory one level higher, and now I get lots of these, even listing circular dependencies like `X -> X`, which can't be because dependencies did not change. Also Internal Error says SCons itself crashed, when it did not find the cycle it thought is there earlier. Need some magic to get rid of this! :(

Comment: It would be nice if there was an explanation of how to go about resolving/removing the cyclic dependency. I just tried again updating to the latest scons (3.0.1) and cant' because of this error. It is not obvious what the issue is. We have a custom builder that just generates a version file, and that is what it seems tripped up on.